# Python actions depending on time

Tags: scripting, python

I want to set up some code that depending on the time of day (internal computer time i guess). It switches to do something else.

Heres in english:

```
y = 1 <br>
if 6:30am then<br>
  x = 1 + y<br>
if 7:00am then<br>
  x = 2 + y<br>
if any_other_time then<br>
  x = 0<br>
```

Here is what i have so far in my script.

```
import time<br>
clock = time.time()
y = 0
if clock < 6:30am
x = 2 + y
```

but i know this isn't right because time.time displays something different then 6:30am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO i would use the datetime library

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

eg.

```
>>> datetime.utcnow()   
datetime.datetime(2007, 12, 6, 15, 29, 43, 79060)
```

check this post too

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599060/how-can-i-get-an-accurate-utc-time-with-python

Comment: how is this looking: http://pastebin.com/uD7xr0bh

Comment: Ohh run ntpclients on your servers too... :D

Comment: haha yeah i do. Trying to set up a bandwidth controller. So that at certain times, it shapes differenly.

Comment: Are you focusing on a single server, or wanting to run it for the network? BTW, looks very interesting :D

Comment: More of a learning experience. I don't need it, but i am trying to teach my self Lartc. So i figured make up tasks a 'boss' would ask. So atleast when i do have a task like this i can already do it, or atleast have reference.